# How to get main meta_key's inner key? Inner key is on json format and need to get result in WordPress WP Query (With pagination)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, pagination

**How to get main meta_key's inner key? Inner key is on json format and need to get result in WordPress WP Query (With pagination)**

**Need solution on main WP_Query argument. Not in inner condition.**

I have custom post type and meta stored in one meta key name is ="lp_listingpro_options" and on that meta key added multiple json data.

"Meta stored in databse on 'lp_listingpro_options' key is:"

**I need to get all Plan_id is = 195**

Can you please help me on that critical issue

```
a:35:{s:12:"tagline_text";s:15:"Atmen ist Leben";s:7:"gallery";s:0:"";s:12:"price_status";s:6:"notsay";s:10:"list_price";s:0:"";s:13:"list_price_to";s:0:"";**s:7:"Plan_id";s:3:"195"**;s:16:"lp_purchase_days";s:0:"";s:11:"reviews_ids";s:0:"";s:15:"claimed_section";s:7:"claimed";s:26:"listings_ads_purchase_date";s:0:"";s:30:"listings_ads_purchase_packages";s:0:"";s:4:"faqs";a:2:{s:3:"faq";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}s:6:"faqans";a:1:{i:1;s:0:"";}}s:14:"business_hours";a:5:{s:6:"Montag";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:5:"08:00";s:5:"close";s:5:"17:00";}s:8:"Dienstag";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:5:"08:00";s:5:"close";s:5:"17:00";}s:8:"Mittwoch";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:5:"08:00";s:5:"close";s:5:"17:00";}s:10:"Donnerstag";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:5:"08:00";s:5:"close";s:5:"17:00";}s:7:"Freitag";a:2:{s:4:"open";s:5:"08:00";s:5:"close";s:5:"17:00";}}s:21:"lp_medical_report_pdf";s:0:"";}
```

Look at the database meta_key stored image is
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/15262224?key=c4c4290515f14fedc7ff39995cc682c7

Answer (score 0):

That meta_value payload is not JSON. Rather, it uses php's serialization format for its objects and arrays.  To look for a particular item in the meta_value, you load it into a php object and examine that object.

You can load it into a php value with [deserialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). But within WordPress you don't need to worry about that. If you use WordPress's [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function it will return the item already deserialized.

Then you examine the array to find what you want.

```php
$listingproOptions = get_post_meta( $postId, 'lp_listingpro_options', true );
print_r( $listingProOptions ); /* remove this line after testing */
if ( isset ($listingproOptions['Plan_id']) ) {
 $planId = $listingproOptions['Plan_id'];
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank for your answer, but after that pagination is not working
So need solution from without add inner condition.
Means need solution on main WP_Query argument.